# Cannot find plural form of table

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core

For some reason code-first EF7 (vNext) will not use/find the plural form of my table.  I have tried adding the table attribute to the model but it does not solve the problem.

```
[Table("Units")]
public class Unit
```

If I name the table Unit then no problem.  If I name the table Units then it's not found.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using any fluent API configuration?

Comment: @DavidG as far as via OnModelCreating no.

Comment: I think attributes may not be implemented yet, try the fluent api instead

Comment: @ErikEJ as far as I understand, and I may not understand, the fluent api is manipulated in the OnModelCreating override.  However, this is no longer a method in EF7.

Comment: Do you have the correct reference and namespaces included: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Using-EF7-in-Traditional-.NET-Applications

Comment: @ErikEJ, OK, this is great.  Adding Microsoft.Data.Entity.Metadata was the reference I needed.  Now how do I indicate here that the "Unit" model should use the "Units" table? Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like you can use the Table extension method from the Relational namespace, but cannot verify just now https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Design-Meeting-Notes---October-2,-2014

Answer (score 3):

This is how I resolved:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Unit>().ToTable("Units");
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, I'm having a very similar problem and your solution doesn't appear to work due to ToTable not existing. What were your usings to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

For Entity Framework 7 beta1, I solved this issue by this way:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Unit>().ForRelational(rb =>
    {
        rb.Table("Units");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework 7 is being configured using the Fluent API. I created an extension method which maps the table names to their plural form, with the intention to reproduce the EF 6 behavior and to be able to use my existing database while working with EF7.

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void PluralizeNames(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var types = modelBuilder.Model.EntityTypes;

        foreach (var type in types.Where(type => type.ClrType != null))
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity(type.ClrType)
                        .ForRelational()
                        .Table(type.ClrType.Name.Split('`')[0].Pluralize());
        };
    }
}
```

Please note the `.Pluralize()` extension method. This may be Humanizer you're using or any other extension method which pluralizes your string. (I shamelessly copied https://github.com/srkirkland/Inflector/blob/master/Inflector/Inflector.cs in my project to be able to compile my project with the DNX Core.)

The `.Split()` part is to deal with the `type.ClrType.Name` which can output stuff like *IdentityUserRole`1*.

You can use it like this in your `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.PluralizeNames();
}
```

*Ps; this works for me*

Answer (score 0):

Now the ToTable and ForRelational both are missing in beta5 of EF7. So I used the below code.

```
       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<Role>().ForSqlServer().Table("Role");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" in your project.json and restore your package.
.NET core is broken down in to small pieces for less memory foot print. So you need to explicitly tell what you want.